# Redirect to product page from observer

Tags: magento2, event-observer, redirect-url

There is one link on my product page. If the customer is not login than its ask for customer login in the popup and after login, I want to redirect that product page.

So, I am using `customer_login` event and in popup login form I am passing product id and save some detail to the database. Now I want to redirect that product page.

in Magento 1 redirect from observer like this

```
$observer->getRequest()->setParam('return_url','http://www.google.com/');
```

so how can I do this from an observer in Magento 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is works

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager
) {
    $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
 }
```

Use `setBeforeAuthUrl` redirect after login

```
$this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session')->setBeforeAuthUrl($productCollection->getProductUrl());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code

```
protected $resultRedirect;

public function __construct(Context $context,ResultFactory $result) {       
        $this->resultRedirect = $result;        
        parent::__construct($context);  
    }
```

Add below code to your function

```
$resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirect->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
$resultRedirect->setUrl('add-url-here');
return $resultRedirect;
```

Comment: Not working...Its redirect to Customer Account page

Comment: Post your code in question